# js file is not linking to HTML file

Tags: html, angularjs

I got a problem with js file. My js file is not linking to HTML file. Please help me.

HTML code:
"

```
  <html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>   
    <script src="repeaters.js"></script>
    <link href = "Repeaters.css" type="text/CSS" rel="stylesheet">
</head>


<body ng-app="repeatModule">   <!-- root module-->


<div ng-controller="controlRepeater">  <!-- controller name--> 

<div>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>ID </tr>
        <tr> NAME</tr>
    </thead>
<tbody >

    <tr ng-repeat="product in products"> <!-- Great. Now let's add the repeat directive. It is important to understand that ngRepeat will repeat itself and its contents for each element in the collection. We must therefore apply it to the <tr> and not the <tbody>. -->
        <td>{{product.id}} </td>
        <td>{{product.name}} </td>

    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>       
</div>
 </div>   

  <div class="oddrow">   
 </div>

</body>

</html> "
```

Below is my Angular js code:

This js file is not linking to HTML code. how can I debug this kind of issues?

```
>   var myApp = angular.module('repeatModule', []) 
   .controller("controlRepeater", ["$scope", function ($scope) { 
   $scope.products = [      
   {id:1, name: "Hockey" }
   {id:2, name: "cricket" }
   {id:3, name: "pool" }
   {id:4, name: "badminton"}];

    }]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array syntax is wrong, you need commas to separate your array items:

```
$scope.products = [      
   {id:1, name: "Hockey" },
   {id:2, name: "cricket" },
   {id:3, name: "pool" },
   {id:4, name: "badminton"}
];
```

Once you fix this, it should work, see this [codepen](http://codepen.io/dariospadoni/pen/VPGVLN?editors=1011).

Comment: Thank you @Dario. sometime i do this kind of silly mistakes